# popen: 'sh: permission denied"

Tags: c, linux, pipe, popen

I'm trying to use popen. When I execute some system command (e.g. let's say ls or whatever) all works fine. But when I'm trying to execute my executable:

```
pipe = popen("./ <path>","r");
```

I get an error:
  sh: permission denied.

Both executables (which uses popen and that one which I want to launch from first one) belong to my user accound and have "x" permissions.

Comment: Is the second "executable" a script with perhaps an invalid #! line at the top? Or does the second executable reside on another drive that is mounted without the 'exec' permissions?

Comment: No, it's a binary and it resides at the same drive. And I can run it from command line, so it seems that it's ok with the executable itself. Ubuntu 12.04 LTS.

Comment: Is the executable really called `<path>`?

Answer (score 0):

I'd double check that error message, since it should say what the permission denied relates too.  i.e. if path was empty, and you just passed ./, or had an extra space like in your example, you should see

sh: ./: Permission denied

As you describe it, it sounds like your getting a permission denied error trying to run /bin/sh; it seems more likely that you misread the error.